# why set MBProgressHUD's hide to YES, but isHidden method is NO?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, mbprogresshud

I am using a `MBProgressHUD` view to show loading state when i am downloading something from the Internet. When download is finished, i call the hide method to hide the view. I want to use a timer to judge whether download is finished by checking the view's hidden, namely, isHidden method. But when i set the view 's hide to **YES**, then check isHidden method, it returns **NO**. I don't know why the view works like this?

some  snippets are as follows:

```
MBProgressHUD   *HUD; // instance variable
```

In the download finished method:

```
[HUD hide:YES];
NSLog(@"HUD isHidden: %@",[HUD isHidden] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

When the method is called, the output is NO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per MBProgressHUD's implementation, they don't hide it using hidden property of UIView. They just sets alpha of MBProgressHUD to 0 so that it will not be visible.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have checked the hide: method implementation. As you said, they set the alpha value to 0 and didn't use the hidden property of UIView. I wonder whether they should update the hidden property ?

Answer (score 4):

**I Found That:**

In `MBProgressHUD` `isHidden` Method By default set **NO** so you can get all time to (*When you check*) `NO`. You doesn't check in superviews.

For Check `MBProgressHUD` Status **hide/show**.

Set  `[HUD setHidden:YES];` after `[HUD hide:YES];` then after it will work fine .

```
NSLog(@"HUD isHidden: %@",[HUD isHidden] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
//Output in consol YES
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I checked the hide implementation, it change the alpha value to 0 to hide the view and didn't update the hidden property. And in your way, i can check the is hidden value.thanks your answer.

Comment: but i think Rahul's answer is better for me. he show me the hide implementation. i will vote for you